# Is there a way to have a placeholder text at Validating String Parameter in a Free-Style Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

as the title says I need a placeholder text for "Validating String Parameter" in a Free-Style job in Jenkins. What I'm mentioning looks as follows.

[image]

But what you see in the image is an Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" and it lets you only put the text into the Filter section. I need a text in the parameter itself and if there isn't any entry Jenkins should consider it as an empty variable. Is that possible if yes how? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is a way through the Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter. The choice type will be Formatted HTML.
The jenkinsfile I use has a parameters block outside of the pipeline block and it is declarative. I'm not sure if this will work with scripted.

```
properties([
  parameters([
    [
      $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
      name: 'INPUT_TEST',
      choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
      description: '',
      referencedParameters: '',
      omitValueField: true,
      script: [
          $class: 'GroovyScript',
          fallbackScript: [
              classpath: [],
              sandbox: false,
              script: 'return [""]'
          ],
          script: [
              classpath: [],
              sandbox: false,
              script: '''
                return '<input name="value" class="jenkins-input" placeholder="Placeholder text here">'
              '''
          ]
      ]
    ]
  )]
)]
```

Note: the name should be "value", the class is optional the jenkins-input will make it look like a String parameter. Placeholder is where you want to have the text.